# JavaScript does not work different domain?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

My project is in two domain. When I open it from my localhost domain scripts are not working. For example in other domain 192.168.1.3/myProject, script are working, but in my localhost for example localhost:49416/myProject, scripts are not working. What could be the problem?

scripts and css refrences like this.Css works.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

for js files, this error occurs: failed to load resource, in localhost.

Thanks.

Comment: the setup for localhost, In other words Paths may be incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure that all files are accessible?

Comment: Yes, all files accessable. I try to find problem, 2 days. But I cant find. css files are working. but scripts are not working

Comment: what happen if, instead of localhost:port/myProject, you go to 127.0.0.1:port/myProject ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if the Javascript is loaded correctly. You can do this by looking into the source code or better with Firebug (FF) or developer tools (IE, Chrome) in the network tab. There it will tell you if the resources have been loaded correctly (status code 200).

If you are certain that the JS is embedded correctly, then check if Javascript is enabled for localhost. Especially Internet Explorer I believe doesn't allow scripts to be run from localhost by default.

If you still have problems check if you have script errors in your code. For example in Firebug under Console.

Comment: I looked source code, there is loading problem. It was not found js file paths. failed to load resource error

Comment: So, how can I fix the problem.

Comment: Does the `@Url.Content` resolve correctly?

Maybe try to use single quotes in `src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")"` so it becomes `src="@Url.Content('~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js')"`

If that doesn't help try to put absolute paths and see if that works.

Comment: yes. Paths are looked correctly. How css files work and js files not? I checkd file access there is not any problem.

Comment: single quotes are very unlikely to work since that is a call to a c# function that expects a string

Comment: I try it all browsers. in other domain it work, in my local does not. two projects are same.

Comment: ok let's try this: open the source code in Firefox. Look for the line where jquery is loaded. Click on the src (it should be a link).
Does it take you to the jquery library? Or does it give you a 404?
Maybe check if the dir is really named `Scripts`and not `scripts`. Sometimes that gives problems, too.

Comment: There is silly mistake. I sorry for everyone. When I copied project from other domain, scripts file is not copied to my domain. Thanks your attentions.